# CSS - Laying images on top of each other relative/absolute

Tags: css, image, position, absolute

I want to lay image2 over image1 and below both of those image4 over image3.  Everything I read recommends: the parent div relative and the children will be absolute within the parent. But all four images are laying over each other. This will end up being responsive so I don't want to set heights. What am I missing?

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <img src="images/image1.jpg" style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0;" />
    <img src="images/image2.jpg" style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0;" />
</div>
<div style="position:relative;">
    <img src="images/image3.jpg" style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0;" />
    <img src="images/image4.jpg" style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0;" />
</div>
```

Comment: what about z-index? [some info here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I am including a snippet, so you understand whats going on when you use absolute. It is basically pushing the items below it, up into its place.

```html
  <div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="width:50px; height:100px; background:red;"></div>
    <div style="width:500px; height:100px; background:blue; position:absolute;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="width:50px; height:100px; background:purple;"></div>
    <div style="width:50px; height:100px; background:yellow;"></div>
  </div>
```

Here is a working demo [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/Born2Code1983/pen/wjNeXX)

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <img src="image1jpg" style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0;" />
    <img src="image2.jpg"  />
</div>
<div style="position:relative;">
    <img src="image3.jpg" style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0;" />
    <img src="image4.jpg" style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0;" />
</div>
```

Comment: I never would have guessed that would work, but it did.  just removing the second position style pushed down the second relative div.  Bravo!